# Некорректно передаются значения в функцию через указатель/ссылку

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки, передача-параметров

Суть задания была в вычислении данного примера[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где нужно было передать в функцию y(x) параметры по значениям, ссылке, и указателю

Код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double SubFunctionValue(double);
double FunctionValue(double, double, double);
double SubFunctionReference(double&);
double FunctionReference(double&, double&, double&, double&);
double SubFunctionPointer(double*);
double FunctionPointer(double*, double*, double*, double*);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    double a = 1.5, b = 3.5, c = 2.2;
    double bc = b * c, b_p_c = b + c, a_p_c = a + c;
    cout << "Начальные значения:\na = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << ", b_p_c = " << b_p_c << ", bc = " << bc << ", a_p_c = " << a_p_c << endl;
    cout << "Начальные значения адресов:\n&a = " << &a << ", &b = " << &b << ", &c = " << &c << ", &b_p_c = " << &b_p_c << ", &bc = " << &bc << ", &a_p_c = " << &a_p_c << endl << endl;

    //transmission by value
    cout << "\nРезультат передачи по значению -\t" << FunctionValue(a, b, c) << endl;
    cout << "\nЗначения после передачи по значению -\na = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << ", b_p_c = " << b_p_c << ", bc = " << bc << ", a_p_c = " << a_p_c << endl;
    cout << "Начальные значения адресов после передачи по значению -\n&a = " << &a << ", &b = " << &b << ", &c = " << &c << ", &b_p_c = " << &b_p_c << ", &bc = " << &bc << ", &a_p_c = " << &a_p_c << endl;
    //transmission by reference
    cout << "\nРезультат передачи по ссылке -\t" << FunctionReference(a, bc, b_p_c, a_p_c) << endl;
    cout << "\nЗначения после передачи по ссылке -\na = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << ", b_p_c = " << b_p_c << ", bc = " << bc << ", a_p_c = " << a_p_c << endl;
    cout << "Начальные значения адресов после передачи по ссылке -\n&a = " << &a << ", &b = " << &b << ", &c = " << &c << ", &b_p_c = " << &b_p_c << ", &bc = " << &bc << ", &a_p_c = " << &a_p_c << endl;
    //transmission by pointer
    cout << "\nРезультат передачи по указателю -\t" << FunctionPointer(&a, &bc, &b_p_c, &a_p_c) << endl;
    cout << "\nЗначения после передачи по указателю -\\na = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << ", b_p_c = " << b_p_c << ", bc = " << bc << ", a_p_c = " << a_p_c << endl;
    cout << "Начальные значения адресов после передачи по указателю -\n&a = " << &a << ", &b = " << &b << ", &c = " << &c << ", &b_p_c = " << &b_p_c << ", &bc = " << &bc << ", &a_p_c = " << &a_p_c << endl;
}


//transmission by value
double SubFunctionValue(double x)
{
    return (x * x) * pow(tan(1 / x), 2);
}
double FunctionValue(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return (SubFunctionValue(a) + SubFunctionValue(b * c)) / (pow(SubFunctionValue(b + c), 2) + pow(SubFunctionValue(a + c), 5));
}

//transmission by value
double SubFunctionReference(double& x) 
{
    x = (x * x) * pow(tan(1 / x), 2);
    return x;
}
double FunctionReference(double& a, double& bc, double& b_p_c, double& a_p_c)
{
    return (SubFunctionReference(a) + SubFunctionReference(bc)) / (pow(SubFunctionReference(b_p_c), 2) + pow(SubFunctionReference(a_p_c), 5));
}

//transmission by pointer
double SubFunctionPointer(double* x_POINTER)  
{
    double result ;
    result = (*x_POINTER * *x_POINTER) * pow(tan(1 / *x_POINTER), 2);
    return result;
}
double FunctionPointer(double* a, double* bc, double* b_p_c, double* a_p_c)
{
    return (SubFunctionPointer(a) + SubFunctionPointer(bc)) / (pow(SubFunctionPointer(b_p_c), 2) + pow(SubFunctionPointer(a_p_c), 5));

}
```

Скриншот вывода (красным подчеркнул саму проблему)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здесь `x = (x * x) * pow(tan(1 / x), 2);` вы изменяете переменную `x`, являющуюся ссылкой. Т.е. изменяете **не** копию, а оригинальную переменную, приходящую из функции `main`. Заменить `x = (x * x) * pow(tan(1 / x), 2); return x;` на `return (x * x) * pow(tan(1 / x), 2);`

Answer (score 2):

> Здесь x = (x * x) * pow(tan(1 / x), 2); вы изменяете переменную x, являющуюся ссылкой. Т.е. изменяете не копию, а оригинальную переменную, приходящую из функции main. Заменить x = (x * x) * pow(tan(1 / x), 2); return x; на return (x * x) * pow(tan(1 / x), 2);

**wololo (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/262953/wololo)**

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, вы зачем меняете переданную по ссылке переменную?

```
 x = (x * x) * pow(tan(1 / x), 2);
return x;
```

Во-вторых, полная ахинея. Препод вам двойку поставит.
Убрать фукнцию
double FunctionValue(double a, double b, double c)
и иже с ними.
Оставить только три  функции double y1(double a, double b, double c), double y2(...реализуйте сами...), double y1(...реализуйте сами...) от одной переменной, но с передачей по значению, по ссылке и по указателю.
Оставить только
double a = 1.5, b = 3.5, c = 2.2;
остальные бэ-мэ удалить.
Вычисления Z производить в виде выражения.
double Z1 = y1(a) + y1(b*c) / (...и так далее...);
double Z2 = ...и так далее...